# How to replace two strings in only one time in java

Tags: java, string, replace

May I know the fastest way to replace two strings in java?

Here is the sample code:

```
String template    = "I replace {0} and {1} at one time".
String replaceZero = "Java";
String replaceOne  = "C#";
template = template.replace("{0}", replaceZero).replace("{1}", replaceOne);
```

I have to write code like this. But I want the fastest way. Like this:

```
String template    = "I replace {0} and {1} at one time".
tempate = template.replace("{0}{1}", replaceZero, replaceOne);
```

Is there any implementations to replace all strings in one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may be looking for `MessageFormat.format`. I can't guarantee that it will work fastest, but your code should be clearer.

```
String template = "I replace {0} and {1} at one time";
String replaceZero = "Java";
String replaceOne = "C#";

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(template, replaceZero, replaceOne));
```

Output: `I replace Java and C# at one time`

Comment: Yes. I want like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Something like,

```
String template = "I replace {0} and {1} at one time";
String replaceZero = "Java";
String replaceOne = "C#";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(template);
sb.replace(sb.indexOf("{0}"), sb.indexOf("{0}") + 3, replaceZero).
    replace(sb.indexOf("{1}"), sb.indexOf("{1}") + 3, replaceOne);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I get

```
I replace Java and C# at one time
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to your input having "{0}" and "{1}"? Is this some kind of requirement outside your control?

If you have control of the input, then I would look at using something like:

```
String.format("I replace %s and %s at one time", "Java", "C#");
```